# Start a Systemd service within a Java application

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I am writing a Java application which can run a systemd service.

I have two systemd services (**service1** and **service2**). **service1** will start the Java application. Then inside the application it should start **service2**.
I used the following statement to start **service2**:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "systemctl start service2"});
```

But service2 is not started. (Command execution happens without any exceptions though) Any idea why?

**Edit:**

I used `sudo systemctl start service1` to start the first service.

Service 1 looks as follows.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service 1

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/test
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
User=las
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar test.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Service 2 looks as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=Service 2

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/test
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
User=las
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar abc.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**Edit 2**

After changing the code in a way to see the output stream of Runtime.getRuntime().exec() I got to know that it is returning the following error.

```
Failed to start service2.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

Comment: which user is running the application? What error messages did you get? What did you do to debug your program?

Comment: @baao I edited the question.

Comment: Problem can be related to permission. Check if you have an error in /var/log/auth.log.

Comment: @cisk please see the Edit 2

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running the first service with the `sudo` call as `las`. The process starts out as `root`, but you explicitly tell it run `service` as `User=las`.

Then, you attempt to call `systemctl start service2`, but this requires root permission and `service` is running as `las`. `systemctl` tries to prompt you for a password, but it can't, because `service1` isn't run in a interactive context, thus the error about "Interactive authentication required".

I'm guessing you may want to use systemd "user" services instead, which would run as your user and not as root, and not require the `User=` directive and would also not require the `sudo` password to launch the service.

I also see that these are graphical apps tied to a particular display, based on your setting the `DISPLAY` variable.

You might which to try using your Desktop's "autostart" feature to have the apps start when your login, rather than by `systemd`..